# android sdk is not specified in android studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio v1.5.1 on ubuntu.  I have android API 16 and 23.  I am trying to build a module using android studio but it complains that the android SDK is not specified.
When I open the project settings, I can see both android 16 and 23.
I cannot seem to figure out which one to select as default (or should I go ahead and delete the one I do not need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done by using File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Name of module -> Dependencies tab -> Selecting Module SDK -> Selecting the SDK I wanted to use (Android SDK 16) -> Apply.  I was able to build the module after the change.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the (general) sdk location with:

```
- File -> Settings ->  Android SDK (under Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings)
```

Also you can set the location for a project using:

```
- File -> Project Struture -> SDK Location
```

**To set the level of the SDK**, use your `build.gradle` file inside the module using:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select more than one, like in screenshot below. They are packages that you have installed.

So no need to worry and no need to delete any similar will be in UBUNTU

[image]